# Masked Textbox C# Winforms Empty If Statment Not Working?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello everyone im currently trying to run an IF statement within C# WinForms that checks whether two masked textboxes have been completed and in that scenario a button will then appear to the user. This is my code:

```
if (maskedTextBox1.MaskFull && maskedTextBox2.MaskFull)
{
    button4.Visible = true;
}
else 
{
    button4.Visible = false;
}
```

When i run my application the buttons visibility is still staying hidden even when my Masked Textboxes have been completed/fully filled in. Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: where did you put the if statement?

Comment: Its under the Initialize component method as i want it to run on the forms start-up , it looks like this: InitializeComponent();
          
            if (maskedTextBox1.MaskFull && maskedTextBox2.MaskFull)
            {
                button4.Visible = true;
            }

Comment: You need to put the statement in TextChanged event of the MaskedTextBox so it get executed whenever user changes the input text.

Answer (score 0):

First, you condition can be a lot shorter: `button4.Visible = (maskedTextBox1.MaskFull && maskedTextBox2.MaskFull);`.
Second, are you sure you need [`MaskFull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.maskfull(v=vs.110).aspx) and not [`MaskCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.maskcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Ok i just put the IF Statement into a masked-textbox like mehrzad suggested but when i now run my application the button appears when the form is loaded but then disappears when anything is written into the masked textboxes. My code is now looking like this:  private void maskedTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (maskedTextBox1.MaskCompleted && maskedTextBox2.MaskCompleted)
            {
                button4.Visible = true;
            }

            else
            {
                button4.Visible = false;
            }
        }

Comment: If you don't want the button to show when the form loads, You can set visibility to false in the designer.

Comment: Sorry i meant "masked textbox text-changed event like mehzad suggested"

Comment: I just tried to set the visibility to false but then the button is not appearing when the masked textboxes have been completed. Its basically not recognizing when these two masked-text boxes have been fully completed.

Comment: @at541 Put a break point on your If statement. Check to see what your values are

Comment: Hello mark , i just did that and it stopped when my IF statement was called , im not sure what to do now as i have never used Breakpoints before.

Comment: @at541 you can inspect your variables to make sure they are what you are expecting by hovering over them or creating a watch for them.

Comment: @at541: This will be a good place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx